# Unity C# Limit Orbit RotateAround Position

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine, quaternions

So this is my code I've made so far, its for a camera orbiting around a point in space.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Lean.Touch;

public class CameraOrbit : TopClass
{
    [Tooltip("Ignore fingers with StartedOverGui?")]
    public bool ignoreGuiFingers = true;

    [Tooltip("Ignore fingers if the finger count doesn't match? (0 = any)")]
    public int requiredFingerCount = 1;

    [Tooltip("The sensitivity of the movement, use -1 to invert")]
    public float sensitivity = 0.25f;

    public Vector3 target = Vector3.zero;

    protected void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Get the fingers we want to use
        List<LeanFinger> fingers = LeanTouch.GetFingers(ignoreGuiFingers, requiredFingerCount);

        // Get the scaled delta of all the fingers
        Vector2 delta = LeanGesture.GetScaledDelta(fingers);

        transform.RotateAround(target, Vector3.up, delta.x * sensitivity);
        transform.RotateAround(target, Vector3.right, delta.y * sensitivity);

        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

This works great so far, however there are 2 things which are annoying and I'm at loss how to fix

1. The biggest one is when the camera reaches the top things can get weird if the user keeps moving up. The camera starts to kind of turn around, the world kind of spins etc... I want the camera to kind of stop when it gets near the top or bottom.
2. The camera's rotation can get weird, I want it to always be pointing up and never rotated to the right or left slightly or fully and especially upside down. Just always pointing up.

I've tried these links after lots of Google searching

- http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MouseOrbitImproved
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/363353/how-to-limit-a-transform-movement-in-x-axis.html
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/438836/limit-camera-rotation-with-rotatearound.html
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/1087351/limit-vertical-rotation-of-camera.html
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/1370422/limit-y-axis-transformrotatearound.html

But none of them worked right or I couldn't get them adapted to what I needed

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: well, before you rotate, check what angle you are at already, then rotate accordingly (full frame rotation, only the remaining angle, or even not at all) the weirdness you experience is probably gimbal lock. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_Lock

Comment: @yes How do I check what angle I'm at and what is full frame rotation and the rest of what you said?

Comment: with full frame rotation i meant the maximum rotation that can happen in a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer so far, I think. I also had someone play test it and they liked it so I may have found the solution.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Lean.Touch;

public class CameraOrbit : TopClass
{
    [Tooltip("Ignore fingers with StartedOverGui?")]
    public bool ignoreGuiFingers = true;

    [Tooltip("Ignore fingers if the finger count doesn't match? (0 = any)")]
    public int requiredFingerCount = 0;

    [Tooltip("The sensitivity of the movement, use -1 to invert")]
    public float sensitivity = 0.25f;

    public float min = 45f;
    public float max = 315f;

    public Vector3 target = Vector3.zero; //this is the center of the scene, you can use any point here

    protected void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Get the fingers we want to use
        List<LeanFinger> fingers = LeanTouch.GetFingers(ignoreGuiFingers, requiredFingerCount);

        // Get the world delta of all the fingers
        Vector2 delta = LeanGesture.GetScaledDelta(fingers);

        transform.RotateAround(target, Vector3.up, delta.x * sensitivity);
        transform.RotateAround(target, Vector3.right, delta.y * sensitivity);

        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        angles.x = Mathf.Clamp(angles.x, min, max);
        angles.y = Mathf.Clamp(angles.y, min, max);
        angles.z = 0;
        transform.eulerAngles = angles;

        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

If I want the camera to always have the up point up, in my case, its keeping the z-axis at 0. The x and y axis just needed to be kept in check.

If it helps anyone, the only thing I modified from above is

```
...
public float min = 45f;
public float max = 315f;
...
Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
angles.x = Mathf.Clamp(angles.x, min, max);
angles.y = Mathf.Clamp(angles.y, min, max);
angles.z = 0;
transform.eulerAngles = angles;
```

Thanks to @yes for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: glad i could help. a minor thing though, i would check the angle *before* i rotate, and only rotate as much as necessary if at all. but as long as it works and doesnt cause issues, it works ;)

Comment: @yes actually, even more funny, while this solution did work, I actually just ended up rotating the object in front of the camera instead of the camera itself. I honestly don't know why I didn't think of this earlier as it largely simplifies the whole thing and allows full rotation without any of the problems or complications of a full-camera orbit and stuff.